# On android framework,Is there any class in which common HTTP HEADER is defined

Tags: android, http-headers

I don't want to defined them again if they are already provided.
So is there something like that:

```
public SomeClass
{
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content_Type";
    public static final String ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" = "Accept-Language"
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One day when I'm reading android sources of apache httpclient on [GitHub](https://github.com/android/platform_external_apache-http);

I found it:

```
https://github.com/android/platform_external_apache-http/blob/master/src/org/apache/http/protocol/HTTP.java
```